# Trying to make mobile Nav Menu with only CSS

Tags: css, mobile, navigation, media-queries

I have been working on this website and am using media queries to adjust the layout of the view according to the screen size. For the mobile phone size I want to hide the navigation that is already in place and just show a simple "Menu" link that when clicked, displays the Nav Menu. I having been doing research, however I am looking for the simplest way possible with the code that I have. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I would like to stay away from javaScript if possible.

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="meetPractioner.html">Meet The Practioner</a></li>
          <li><a href="servicesRates.html">Services &#38; Rates</a></li>
          <li><a href="bookAppointment.html">Book Appointment</a></li>
          <li><a href="locationHours.html">Location &#38; Hours</a></li>
          <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="questions.html">Questions &#38; Answers</a></li>
          <li><a href="benefits.html">Benefits of Massage</a></li>
          <li><a href="bodySense.html">Body Sense Magazine</a></li>


        </ul>
          <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a> 
     </nav>
```

This is my jsFiddle that shows the CSS and the rest of the code. http://jsfiddle.net/Floyd/v723oqfc/

Comment: Clicking will involve javascript. There are 'hacks' ...try searching for 'checkbox hack' but JS would be simpler...especially with your current HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you could do is:

Create a button called menu-bttn with the css:

```
a.menu-bttn {
    display: none;
    //Other properties
}

//You should really use javascript or jquery for button click rather than CSS
a.menu-bttn:focus > nav ul li a {
    display: block;
}

...

@media only screen and (max-width:WIDTH) {
    a.menu-bttn {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        //positioning
    }
 }
```

JQuery Click Approach:

```
    <script>
    function toggleMenu() {
        $('nav ul li a').slideToggle("fast");
    }
    </script>

    <a onclick="toggleMenu()" class="menu-bttn">Menu</a>
```

OR

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-bttn').click(function() {
        $('nav ul li a').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>

<a class="menu-bttn">Menu</a>
```

Documentation On SlideToggle: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

You dont HAVE to use SlideToggle, there are other options:
Documentation On Toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Pure Javascript Approach:

```
<script>
var bttn = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-bttn');
var bttn = bttn[0];

function toggleMenu() {
    var menu = document.getElementsById(//Id Of nav ul li a elements);
    if (menu.style.display === 'none')
        menu.style.display = 'block';
    else
        menu.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<html>
...
<a onclick="toggleMenu()" class="menu-bttn">Menu</a>
...
</html>
```

Comment: I like this approach, however I am not getting the nav menu to display when using the button

Comment: ok so button clicks in CSS are a little tricky, the '>' means that nav ul li a has to be a direct descendent of the menu-bttn and since this isnt the case. Your best bet would be to use javascript or jquery to show/hide.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I am new to jquery, is there one that would easily work with my code?

Comment: Yep, I added an example above

Comment: Great, I will try these out and see if I can get them to work for me.

Comment: I am unable to click on the link with either. I am getting the button to change color on the hover, however my cursor is changed from the arrow to a text line.

Comment: Well, if you want your cursor to be a pointer when you hover over a button add: 

cursor: pointer;

to the css properties of the button

Comment: I keep getting toggleMenu is not defined and an unexpected syntax error : unexpected token for meetThePractioner.html:22